# How can I set default today date using datepicker with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I am using the jQuery datepicker(http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html) and I would like to set today's date on the calendar to a date of my choosing that never changes rather than take the system date as today's date. How can I set that up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **defaultDate** option.

For example in order to set default date to week ago:

> $.datepick.setDefaults({defaultDate: -7});

Comment: very nice. Thank you! I am using the minDate and maxDate settings and for some reason those won't work together with defaultDate. I can't figure out why though.

Comment: I figured out you can't use the '+3' setting on maxDate if using a custom date for defaultDate. I will have to specify a date for the minDate and maxDate.

Answer (score 1):

I believe he has an example under the default date tab on the link you provided. Am I mistaken?